# Custom CSS based on the lang property of the HTML document

Tags: css, lang, arabic-support

What is wrong with this CSS?

```
/* Arabic — Switch off Italic because the internal HTML viewer can't display the characters */
[lang=ar] .cellAYFM, .cellCBS, .cellHEADING, .cellLAC, .cellOtherHeading, .cellTFGW, .cellWEEKEND {
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I want to do some custom styling if the HTML document is set to "ar". But it is being applied no matter what `lang` property I am using for the document.

I have used the above syntax to style the `table` elements OK in my file but it is not working for the `td` elements.

## Update

If I use:

```
[lang=ar] .cellAYFM, [lang=ar] .cellAYFM, [lang=ar] .cellAYFM, [lang=ar] .cellCBS, [lang=ar] .cellHEADING, [lang=ar] .cellLAC, [lang=ar] .cellOtherHeading, [lang=ar] .cellTFGW, [lang=ar] .cellWEEKEND {
    font-style: normal;
}
```

It works. I was just hoping to not have to repeat `[lang=ar]` somehow.

Comment: may be try giving [lang=ar] .tableClassName td{
font-style: normal;
}

Comment: Unless you are using SCSS/SASS/LESS (which would compile to what works for you anyway), you can't get around this since you need to specify the parent (HTML) for each element. Or, if you have access to the HTML markup generation, you could add the class `ar` or something similar to each element that you need to style, and then use `[lang=ar] .ar { font-style: normal }` so the styles would only get applied when the language is set.

Comment: @saravana that would only work for `td` elements. OP would still need to specify for the `th`, `tr` as well...which is the point of this question.

Comment: @disinfor The main point was if I had to prefix each class override with `[lang=ar]` or not. But I now see that I must do.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle yeah, I understand what you are trying to accomplish, hence my comment.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I realized you could use the wildcard selector. I posted my answer. I'm not sure what your HTML looks like, so you may have to adjust the table class.

Answer (score 3):

This might help i guess .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.my-table .cell-heading:lang(it) { 
  background: yellow;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<table class="my-table" lang="it">
<tr class="cell-heading"><th>head1</th><th>head2</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a **CSS variable** only for arabic and use it in your rules.

At the beginning of your CSS, declare the variable:

```
html[lang="ar"] {
  --ArabicStyle: normal;
}
```

At the end of each affected rule (e.g. `.cellAYFM`), add a second font-style property:

```
font-style:var(--ArabicStyle);
```

This way, you could get rid of the extra rule you specified.

Comment: Not quite sure how this works. The css is multi lingual so we already have a primary class which is ok for most situations. Then for specific circumstances I need to override the styling. In this instance I had several classes to revise and didn't think I needed the `[]` prefix before every class, but I do.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `*` wildcard selector for your tables. I used a div to wrap with the `lang` attribute to demonstrate.

```css
[lang=ar] .table * {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

.table * {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div lang="ar">
  <table class='table'>
    <th>Test</th>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>


<div>
  <table class='table'>
    <th>Test</th>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers with your suggestions.

I think in the end it was best to do it this way:

```
/* Arabic — Switch off Italic because the internal HTML viewer can't display the characters */
[lang=ar] .cellAYFM, 
[lang=ar] .cellCBS, 
[lang=ar] .cellHEADING, 
[lang=ar] .cellLAC, 
[lang=ar] .cellOtherHeading, 
[lang=ar] .cellTFGW, 
[lang=ar] .cellWEEKEND {
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I appreciate I had not provided the HTML data to give context.

Once again, thanks for your suggestions.